# Integration and unit test cases for MS teams bot using bot framework adapter

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I have a bot application that sends proactive messages to the MS team's chat. I have a few interactions in that chat that open up task modules.

The task modules in a few scenarios are for view only but in some cases, it is a write action where submit is involved.

My bot interacts with my backend service to perform CRUD operations from task modules.

I want to build the test environment(unit + integration) where the following are the use cases

1. The messages are sent proactively.
2. On clicking the button, the task module opens
3. The task module has relevant views
4. The task module data is submitted to the bot
5. The bot interaction with my backend services works

I was exploring [bot-tester](https://github.com/microsoftly/BotTester) and [learn-microsoft-unit-test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/unit-test-bots?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript) but they do not cover all the user cases.

Can someone please help?